# Chrome browser calculates the wrong element width

Tags: html, css, firefox, webkit, chromium

I am working with the text element that needs to be displayed vertically.

To do so I use the following CSS:

```
transform: rotate(180deg);
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
```

However, in Chromium (and other Blink browsers) the width of that element is calculated very weirdly.

To one-time fix that problem there are many ways:

- Open DevTools (F12), set fixed width for that element (`width: 1px`) and disable that option, all goes ok.
- Change the window width to a bit smaller.
- Play around with the smaller text - delete line breaks (`<br>`), type in more or less text and etc.

Couldn't recreate the same fixes in JSFiddle. However here it is for you to see what I mean. Try opening it in browser using WebKit and other engine (i.e. Firefox) - there are different results.

https://jsfiddle.net/VoG__/qfkgt7m9/7/

Also I'm using Debian 8, but the problem appears on any OS.

What is the problem? How can I fix this issue using CSS?

```css
.content {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #bbb;
}
.project-info {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
.project-info .item {
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.project-info .item .heading {
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
.project-info .item .text {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="project-info">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="heading">Item long text</div>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam molestie malesuada sem, ac elementum justo rhoncus vitae. Morbi nec ex quam. Donec finibus auctor odio, non faucibus ex tristique nec.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="heading">Item</div>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam molestie malesuada sem, ac elementum justo rhoncus vitae. Morbi nec ex quam. Donec finibus auctor odio, non faucibus ex tristique nec.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update 29.09.2020**

The issue seems to be gone in the latest version of Chrome (and like), can't reproduce it in Firefox as well. Would accept the answer providing a screenshot of how it looked in older versions and telling why could that happen and what exactly fixed it.

Comment: Note that Chrome is not a webkit browser but uses Blink instead (though it originally came from webkit). Also note that webkit browsers have not needed those vendor prefixes in many versions and years ago and no current Microsoft browser needs them.

Comment: Hmmm...this is something to do with the border on `.item`...if you toggle it off the width reverts to the correct size.

Comment: @Paulie_D Can't reproduce your solution. Are you sure it is about border? Because in the code inspector I see that it's about excess width on the text.

Comment: When I inspect the snippet with developer tools and toggle the border the width resets to normal. I can't reproduce this in Codepen though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that this is something to do with linebreaks / wordbreaks ...

So the first (raw) solution is to keep all the heading text in one line.

```
.project-info .item .heading {
  ...
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

However I'm still looking for a proper answer to allow the heading text stack up in multiple lines.